# How to get decimal value after avg calculation in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, grouping

I have following 2 collection schema

```
images:{
  imageId:"string", avgRating:{ rating1:decimal,rating2:decimal}, ratingCount:int}
}

ratings:{
  imageId:"string", rating1:decimal, rating2:decimal
}

//here rating1 nd rating2 are ratings for different features(just according to my requirements)
```

so I am calculating avg as follows

```
db.images.aggregate([
        {
          $match: {
            imageId: "someid",
          },
        },
        {
          $lookup:
          {
            from: "ratings",
            let: {id: '$imageId'},
            pipeline: [
              {
                $match: {
                  {
                    $eq: ['$imageId','$$id']
                  },
                },
              },{
                $group:
                {
                  _id: 0,
                  aggRating1: {$avg: "$rating1"},
                  aggRating2: {$avg: '$rating2'},
                  count: {$sum: 1}
                }
              },
              {$project: {_id: 0,count:1,aggRating1:1,aggRating2:1}},
            ],
            as: "rating"
          }
        },
        {
          $set: {
            ratingCount: '$count',
            'avgRating.rating1':'$review.aggRating1'
            'avgRating.rating2':'$review.aggRating2'
          }
        },

      ]);
```

I am getting results like this

```
  "data":[
     {
       "_id": "somedocId",
       "imageId":"someid",
       "ratingCount": 10,
       "avgRating": {
        "aggRating1": [
         "rating1":{
          "$numberDecimal": "3.25"
        }],
        "aggRating2": [
          "rating2":{
          "$numberDecimal": "3.25"
        }]
      },
       "rating":[
        {
          "aggRating1": {
            "$numberDecimal": "3.25"
          },
         "aggRating2": {
            "$numberDecimal": "3.25"
          },
          "count": 10
        }
      ],
     }
  ]
```

So if u see when I set the aggRating1 and aggRating2 from rating lookup I got, it converts to array. But in rating it is an object. Idk why is that happening.
So how do i get just the decimal value of the avg results? and not like above? :/

Comment: What tool are you using to run your aggregation?

Comment: i am using nodejs in backend with mongodb query in it

Comment: It is MongoDB `NumberDecimal` data type. This is used for precise decimal numbers, like currency values, etc. You can convert it to other data types, like double, for example. Use the aggregate operator `$convert`.

Comment: I have edited my question. that is what i am getting in results

Comment: You can use the `$map` aggregate operator.

Comment: Yeah i am trying but still either i get empty array or same results :/ this is what i tried 'avgRating.rating1': {   $map:    {    input: "$rating.aggRating1",    as: "decimalValue",    in: {value:"$$decimalValue"} } },